# Need to generate exponentional matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need generate matrix in form like this

[image: Exponential Matrix]

without using any loops in Matlab. Where N has to be some var. I need some hints or way how to solve this.

Comment: The answer to your question is “yes”. I bet that’s a rather unsatisfying answer though. I suggest you be accurate when asking your  question, so that you can avoid getting answers that don’t help you.

Comment: Well I would like to have some hints how can I solve it.

Comment: Then please [edit] the post so it’s clear what answer you would like to get. Read [ask] also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two simple ways to do this. Here are some hints:

1. It can be done using [element-wise multiplication](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html) of a row and column vector with [singleton expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/).
2. Alternatively, it can be done with [matrix-multiplication](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) of a column times a row vector (in that order).

I recommend that you read the pages linked above and give it a try yourself. Here are my solutions:

1. Using singleton expansion:

> `N = 5; C = (0:N-1).*(0:N-1).'`

2. Using matrix multiplication:

> `N = 5; C = (0:N-1).'*(0:N-1)`

Comment: Ohhh sure its a simple outer product, hint was helpful thank you :)